# Find the area of the biggest rectangle that can be inscribed under the graph?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Find the area A of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed under the curve of the equation below in the first and second quadrants. $$y = e^{-x^2}$$

Graph of the equation.

[image]

I don't know where to start. The book says look at chapter 5.4 but there is no example like this at all.

Comment: *Hint:* Whatever the area-maximizing rectangle is, it should have a symmetric breadth of $x = -u \to u$ for some $u > 0$. In which case the area $A = A(u) = 2ue^{-u^2}$. Now apply your standard calculus tricks to find the $u$ that maximizes $A$.

Comment: take some real number $t$ that will be the width from 0 to the positive line.  Then $2 \cdot t \cdot \exp^{-t^2}$ will be the function of the rectangle. Now use derivatives to find the maximum.

Comment: With a parameter $a > 0,$ a rectangle to be investigated will have vertices $(a,0);$ $(-a,0);$ $(a, e^{-a^2});$ $(-a, e^{-a^2}).$ What is its area, as an expression in $a?$

Comment: [Graph of solution](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5pDt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Clearly the top corners of the rectangle should both lie on the curve, so the corners of the rectangle will be at $\langle x,0\rangle$, $\langle x,e^{-x^2}\rangle$, $\langle -x,0\rangle$, and $\langle -x,e^{-(-x)^2}\rangle$ for some $a>0$. Write down a formula for the area of that rectangle as a function of $x$, and use the usual techniques to find where that function has its maximum.